# xstring + format decimal number + scilab

Tags: format, numbers, decimal, scilab

I am not getting to format strings using xstring command. For example:

Mp=54.5666666

xstring(1,1,'$\LARGE Mp={'+string(Mp)+'}%$')

I want only: Mp=54.56%
How do I do?
Besides this, it is possible to define some position using "xstring" only by
click in figure?
"Fontsize" command doesn't work in xstring?
Can anybody help me?
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the answer to the first part of your question on the Scilab's users mailing list:

http://mailinglists.scilab.org/Scilab-users-xstring-format-decimal-number-tp4041406p4041407.html

For the remaining questions:

1. you can use `xclick` to get the screen coordinates and give them to `xstring`:

```
[f,x,y]=xclick()
xstring(x,y,"Some text")
```

2. changing the font size of the text can only be done afterwards like this

```
xstring(x,y,"$y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$")
gce().font_size=5
```

A remark: you don't need to use LaTeX size commands (like `\Large`) as changing the font_size attribute also scales the LaTeX output.

Comment: Excellent!!Thanks a lot!! Best regards!!